# Is it possible to return a 404 from ASP.NET Core 6 MVC middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with both view-based controllers and API controllers. I'd like to be able to disable certain controllers through configuration, and I have a middleware that works:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
        context.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("controller", out var controller);

        if (controller != null)
        {
            if (!_allowControllers.IsMatch(controller as string))
                context.Abort();
            else if (_denyControllers.IsMatch(controller as string))
                context.Abort();
        }

        await next(context);
}
```

However when triggered, the client gets a broken connection.  Is it possible to return a "404" instead?  I've tried

```
context.Response.Redirect("/notfound");
```

instead of `Abort`, but it doesn't seem to work for the API controllers.

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work" what exactly do you mean? What ends up being sent to the client?

Comment: After the code above runs, so does the API controller.  The client sees exactly the same API response as if the above code wasn't there.

Comment: Do you try"context.Response.StatusCode = 404;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want so called short-circuiting/terminal middleware i.e. one which does not invoke (or does not always invoke) `next`. Something like the following:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    context.Request.RouteValues.TryGetValue("controller", out var controller);

    if (controller is string str 
        && (!_allowControllers.IsMatch(str) || _denyControllers.IsMatch(str)))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
    else
    {
        await next(context);    
    }
}
```

Read more:

- [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)